# How to like and comment on facebook posts from native ios app?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to know how to like post of facebook from native ios app and comment on post via native ios app. please provide any kind of sample code from the same.I am newbie.Any kind of help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com) website he has many tutorials on how to implement this.  He also has a great book on using the new social framework with Facebook and twitter.  It is a great resource.

Comment: can u please provide the exact source , I have tried alot but of no use.:(

Comment: The book is called iOS 6 by tutorial.  On page 852, it shows how to like something.  The graph api doesn't allow you to like posts, but you can like a photo.  You just need to know the items id, which you can get via your URL in your browser, or using the graph api console.  Hop this helps.